# A combination algorithm in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

```
import copy

def combine(l, n):
    answers = []
    one = [0] * n
    def next_c(li = 0, ni = 0):
        if ni == n:
            answers.append(copy.copy(one))
            return
        for k in range(li, len(l)):
            one[ni] = l[k]
            next_c(k+1, ni+1)
    next_c()
    return answers

print(combine([1,2,3,4],2))
```

Recently I found this code on internet. It works very well. However, I do not know the details that how does it work？ So can anybody tell me how does it work? And how to understand a recursive code quickly? Thanks very much

Comment: There is a standard implementation for `combinations` in the `itertools` module. The one you've found uses an inner recursive function to create the combinations. Try printing out the intermediate results to see what is happening.

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service. Also you don't even say what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: This isn't actually even recursive, it's iterative.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a newer of SO. I will care next time.

Answer (score 1):

As @AChampion said, You could also get the combinations with the itertools library, which is much easier to understand:

```
import itertools

def combine2(lst, n):
    return [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, n)]
```

Output:

```
>>> combine2([1,2,3,4],2)
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```